# Docker Compose - Running a python script (container 1) from airflow schedule (container 2)

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I have noticed that airflow released some functions to run notebooks using papermill:

```
run_this = PapermillOperator(
    task_id="run_example_notebook",
    input_nb="/tmp/hello_world.ipynb",
    output_nb="/tmp/out-{{ execution_date }}.ipynb",
    parameters={"msgs": "Ran from Airflow at {{ execution_date }}!"}
)
```

I am trying to use airflow (located on container 1) to run some notebooks using anaconda env (located on container 2).

[Containers Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia0Cu.jpg)

What I have done:

1- Create an airflow docker image:

```
FROM puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.2

USER root
RUN groupadd --gid 999 docker \
    && usermod -aG docker airflow
USER airflow
```

2- Create a miniconda image, that contains all the notebooks I would like to run:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda

ENV EXECUTION_ID 111111

RUN conda install -y python=3.6.8 \
    && conda update conda  

RUN conda install -y notebook ipykernel \
&& ipython kernel install --user

RUN pip install papermill 

RUN mkdir notebook \
    && mkdir notebook/output

COPY code.ipynb ./notebook/code.ipynb
COPY params.yaml ./notebook/params.yaml
COPY run.sh ./notebook/run.sh

WORKDIR notebook
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "./run.sh"]
```

3- Create a docker compose file:

I am using this one: [github-docker-compose](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/docker-compose-CeleryExecutor.yml)

However, I am still confused what should I add into this docker compose in order to establish conection between miniconda env, and airflow (located on 2 different containers).

What do you guys recommend to do ?